# Java Count assignment

Tags: java, file, count

I'm trying to write a Java program where it counts the number of people coming to a party from an input file. The file will always be in this format, for example:

[image: file format]

The user will not know how many lines are in the input format. The program will return how many people are coming to the party and how many aren't. The following is my current code:

[image: Current code]

I want my output to be like this example.

[image: Desired output]

However, I am getting this error.

[image: Error]

Any way I can fix this and improve my code to get the desired format?

Comment: Welcome to SO,Please don't put your code as image files,as it is difficult to run your code from an image.

Comment: Also java is case sensative NextLine is not similar to nextLine()

Comment: So, not to be repetitive, but the reason you (the OP) have been down-voted is most likely due to the fact that you posted your code as an image. Please post the actual text next time. Looking at your account I see you're new so I just wanted to inform you of this. However, this is also the second time someone mentioned this to you. Anyways, good luck with your coding!

Comment: Help on how to use StackOverflow's formatting can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You should learn how to interpret and fix compiler errors, when posting here you should post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and code that doesn't even compile doesn't meet those requirements.

Comment: haha i don't really care about being downvoted. just need to get what i need. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mixture of `Scanner` and `BufferedInputStream`. Just choose one and stick to it.
Or better yet - use the modern [`Files#lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
Map<Boolean, Long> counts =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("partyResponses.txt"))
         .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.endsWith("yes"),
                                            Collectors.counting()));

System.out.printf("%d happy friends coming to the July 4th party!%n", counts.get(true);
System.out.printf("%d sad friends can't make it%n", counts.get(false);
```

Comment: `partitioningBy` guarantees that a value is present for true and false; no need for `getOrDefault`. Whilst this is a "neat" solution, it doesn't really help OP to understand what the actual problem in his/her code is.

Comment: @AndyTurner a short test shows you are correct WRT `partitioningBy`'s behavior with empty true/false keys, but I can't find this documented anywhere. Can you share a reference to this?

Comment: @AndyTurner what I'm really trying to ask is whether this behavior is documented, and not just an OpenJDK implementation quirk.

Comment: it is undocumented behaviour in Java 8, but is documented from [Java 9 onwards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-). (If you search, you can find the Java bug asking for it to be documented, evidencing its existence in Java 8).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should be careful about the directory of your response file:

[image]

This code works :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PartyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String filename = "responses.txt";
        int yesResponses = 0;
        int noResponses = 0;
        String line;
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {     
                    if(line.contains("no")){
                        noResponses++;
                    }else{
                        yesResponses++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(yesResponses + " happy friends coming to the July 4th party!");
                System.out.println(noResponses + " sad friends can't make it.");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanky you! How can i make the program print out a message that file is not found and automatically close the file if the file does not exist?

Comment: When "BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));" statement is inside of the try block , file will be closed automatically by BufferedReader when exiting block:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: To print a special message when file is not found , you can add System.out.println("Special message"); statement inside of catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } block